# Spark Streaming MQTT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mqtt, spark-streaming

I've been using spark to stream data from kafka and it's pretty easy.

I thought using the MQTT utils would also be easy, but it is not for some reason.

I'm trying to execute the following piece of code.

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("amqStream").setMaster("local")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val kafkaProducerActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[KafkaProducerActor])

  MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, "tcp://localhost:1883", "AkkaTest")
    .foreachRDD { rdd =>
      println("got rdd: " + rdd.toString())
      rdd.foreach { msg =>
        println("got msg: " + msg)
      }
    }

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The weird thing is that spark logs the msg I sent in the console, but not my println.

It logs something like this:

> 19:38:18.803 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG
>   o.a.s.s.receiver.BlockGenerator - Last element in
>   input-0-1435790298600 is SOME MESSAGE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` is a distributed action, so your println may be executing on the workers. If you want to see some of the messages printed out locally, you could use the built in `print` function on the DStream or instead of your `foreachRDD` collect (or take) some of the elements back to the driver and print them there. Hope that helps and best of luck with Spark Streaming :)

Comment: I just realize my problem is with the MQTT Stream. Using Kafka Stream, I can even running an embedded spark version using the .master("local") and debug my application. Running the MQTT Stream, I can't test that. Testing in the cluster node, it works. =(

Comment: If you want to run in local mode, try using a master of "local[4]" so that the receiver and other can also run.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to just print incoming messages, try something like this instead of the for_each (translating from a working Python version, so do check for Scala typos):

```
val mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, "tcp://localhost:1883", "AkkaTest")
mqttStream.print()
```